# Should I stop editing tags of [geometric-probability] questions?

Tags: discussion, retagging

I recently deleted or added the tag [geometric-probability] too a lot of questions and I feel concerned by the problems pointed out in [this other post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13670/should-adding-one-mildly-relevant-tag-be-considered-a-significant-edit).
I apologize if my behavior have spamed the front page, this was not my intention. A consequence of these many edits is that I received reputation points that I probably don't deserve since I did not actually help on many questions (and I would not be offended if a moderator delete these reputation points).

I explain my behavior.
I started recently to look through the questions with the tag [geometric-probability] because I am personally interested by this subject.
There are not so many questions listed with this tag and a good proportion of them were wrongly taged since they were about geometric sequences and had no link with geometry.
So I started deleting the wrong tag from these question to make the list of questions of this tag more clear.
In a second time I realized that I actually missed questions concerning geometric-probability because they were not taged with it.
I started then to look for them, read them, add the corresponding tag and add a comment or an answer to a few them (which is a really small proportion).

The questions listed with this tag are not many and I thought it would be relevant to have a better list of them. I also think, that someone else might at some point look at the list of the question with this tag and it then it makes sense if the list is quite complete.

I am aware that I don't have a huge experience in this community, so I stop my personal quest and I listen to the more experimented people.
Should I stop adding this tag to old questions?

Answer (score 12):

I've seen a couple of your edits where you removed clearly misused tag — IMO that was perfectly reasonable and useful thing to do.

Just don't edit too many old question in a short period of time. (We have a lot of question now — so about 10 question a day is definitely OK, I think.)

Answer (score 8):

I think that re-categorizing old posts with *appropriate* tags is quite useful - and so is removing wrong tags; so no, there's nothing wrong with your project. Some things to keep in mind, though:

- Don't edit numerous old questions at once, since it fills up the valuable space on the front page. If you limit yourself to $3$ or $4$ old questions a day, I think that's perfectly fine. $50$ in two days is excessive, though.
- Make sure that there's nothing else that should be improved about the post - if there are multiple issues, please either fix all (or many) of them, or leave the post alone. This prevents the same post from having to be edited (and returned to the front page) multiple times. I tend to reject tag-only edits on posts that are more than a few hours old, unless the tags were very poorly applied.

Comment: Actually, with the rate our front page is filling up, doing exactly one per hour is probably hardly noticeable (that is almost 50 in two days). What is usually more noticeable is the short-time average rate: if you do 10 in one hour, once a week, people will still get annoyed because of its visibility.